# std::mapの初期化を綺麗にしたい(続き)

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

[std::mapの初期化を綺麗にしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91776/stdmap%e3%81%ae%e5%88%9d%e6%9c%9f%e5%8c%96%e3%82%92%e7%b6%ba%e9%ba%97%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

がクローズされ、[続きとして質問した内容](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91811) が削除されているため、保全しておきます。

綺麗なコードというのが主観的だと思うのは勝手ですが、この質問は十分に技術的であり、それ以外に正しい表現方法がありません。
議論するつもりもないのですが、正解が1つしかない回答を求めてるわけではなく、続きの質問自体が残らないことに対処の不適切さを感じるので、保全した次第です。

Comment: 書いてあるとおり議論をするつもりもあなたの考えをどうにかするつもりもありません。そんな能動的なアクションではないので、何とも思わなければ誰も何もしないまま終わりますよ。

Comment: 正解がひとつしかない回答を求めているわけではないというのは (クローズされる理由であるところの) 主観的であるということの言い換えにすぎません。 相談の類が必要であれば相談をコンセプトとするサイトをご利用ください。

Comment: 言い換えだと思うのも別サイトにしてほしいと思うのも勝手ですが、そういう議論をしたいわけではないのですよ。

Comment: Stackoverflow はモデレータによる積極的な管理を是として品質を維持しています。
基準に照らしてクローズされるべきであるとモデレータが認めればクローズされるのは通常の手順です。
指摘に従って内容を訂正するか、納得いかないのであれば基準の適用を変更する努力 (議論) をしてください。
どちらもせずに再投稿を繰り返すという迷惑行為の理由として「したくない」が通用するわけないでしょう……。

Comment: @齊藤敦志 このサイトが「モデレータによる積極的な管理を是として」いるというのは誤解です。
[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)には、モデレーターは「まれな例外的状況」を処理する「人間例外処理機」と説明されています。
「モデレーション作業の多くは、明らかなスパムの削除、まったくトピックから外れている質問のクローズ、サイト上の評価が非常に悪いものの処分など、ありふれたものです。理想のモデレーターは、できるだけ操作をしないようにします」とあります。

Comment: なるほど。 その点は誤解だったようです。 しかし、逆に言えば今回の例はそれでも対処すべきと考えた事例ということですね。

Comment: 迷惑行為という認識はありませんよ。議論をするつもりもありません。

Comment: 「迷惑行為という自覚は無い」は免罪符になりません。 そう受け取られかねない行動をしているとアドバイスが付いているので、耳を傾けてみてください。 / 何か確固たる自身の信念に則って行動されているようですが、このサイトにも一定のルール (ガイドライン) があります。再三のアドバイスにも関わらず「低評価」な質問を繰り返していると、システムによる (一時的な) [投稿禁止の措置](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) が取られる可能性があることもお伝えしておきます。

Comment: 誰も具体的に迷惑してないからですよ。移動してなければ何も起きてません。

Comment: よく経緯を把握できていませんが、本人が議論を望んでいるか否かは、個人の意見であり、CC に基づくWiki的な要素のあるこのサイトにおいても、他者が変更してよい部分では無いです。
議論が必要と思う人がいるのであれば、その人の名と責任においてメタサイトに投稿すべきでした。
そもそも、メタでの質問として文章が成立していません。
私は移行に反対し、クローズ票を入れます。
また、極度に例外的な事態なため、モデレータ権限による対応を求め、通報いたします。

Comment: mjy さんが指摘の通り、このままの内容でメタに移行してしまうのは少し強引だったと思うので、メインサイト上の投稿は元に戻した上でいったんクローズしました (詳しくはコメント欄を参照してください)。一連のやり取りに対して議論がもし必要であるなら、関連する投稿を引用する形で構わないのでメタで新規投稿としてください。

Comment: 明らかにこの質問はmetaではありません。元のサイトに戻してください。

Answer (score 6):

ヘルプセンターの [/help/dont-ask](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) に書かれているように、スタック・オーバーフローでは感想を募集するような質問を明示的に禁じています。このサイトで取り扱う質問のスコープを絞り、ユーザー全体のコミュニティによって運営しやすくするために設けることにした慣習です。

[クローズとなったご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91811/19110)では質問文で明確にソースコードに対する感想を募集しており、クローズせざるを得ませんでした。[最初のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91776/19110)ではまだ「`std::map` の初期化をコンストラクタや初期化リストを使って綺麗に書きたい」という客観的な指標があったので、こちらのご質問は個人的にはクローズするほどではないと考えています。

Stack Exchange 全体に目を向けると、英語ではありますが今回のような質問のために [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) というサイトが別途ございますので、こちらに投稿することをご検討ください。

また、付随していくつか補足です：

- 質問や回答が削除されても、その投稿者は閲覧することができます。つまり論理削除です。ご自身で再度同じ投稿をなさる必要はありません。
- サイトのトピックに沿っていない投稿の一部を非公開にするのには、サイト内での検索性を高めて欲しい Q&A に辿り着きやすくするメリットがあります。削除された投稿について何もアクション無しに再投稿されましても、再度同じように削除フローが走ります。
- 質問のクローズについては、質問文を編集し意図をより伝わりやすくして再オープンを促したり、メタなどでクローズに反対し再オープン票を募ったりすることができます。特に[最初のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91776/19110)については私は再オープンで妥当だと思っており、コミュニティに投げかける価値があると感じています。ヘルプセンターの [/help/reopen-questions](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) に詳しく書かれています。

dameo さんは何度か「議論をするつもりはない」という意思を示してらっしゃり、個人的にはその意思自体は尊重したいのですが、残念ながら投稿の改善もクローズ是非の議論もなさらないのであれば今回の一連の質問をこのサイトで取り扱うことは難しいです。

※この回答は、クローズされた質問につけていた[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91811/stdmap%E3%81%AE%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E5%8C%96%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AE%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F#comment104520_91811)の焼き直しです。

Comment: 残念ながら回答にはなっていません。コメントの方に記述すべきですよね。

Comment: @dameo いいえ、回答であっています。このサイトは「メタ」といって、メインサイトの使い方について話すための場所であり、技術的な質問をする場所ではありません。他の方の投票によってこの質問自体がメインサイトからメタに移行されたので多少分かりにくくなってはいます。

Comment: サイトと食い違うなら質問の移動先が適切ではないだけですよ。回答にはなっていません。コメントの方に記述すべきですよね。

Comment: 残念ながら、dameo さんにとってこの質問をする場所がメタでないのであれば、あとは質問自体の削除くらいしか取れる手がありません。また質問の移行が不適切であったと考えるのであれば、そのことをメタに新しく質問として投稿することはできます。ですが、個人的にはこちらのご質問についてはメインサイトではクローズするかメタに移行するかくらいしか選択肢が無かっただろうと思います。これらを免れるための方法は私のこの回答で説明しているとおりですが、それはしたくないということであれば、特に変わることはないですね……。

Comment: 必要のないことをしてるだけですよ。そのまま元のサイトで質問を残しておけばいいだけです。私の労力もあなたの労力も無駄に消費されてるだけですから。

Answer (score 1):

より良いコード求める質問はこれまでにも何度か見かけていますし、わたしも投稿したことがあります。
ですからこういう質問をしたくなる気持ちは個人的にとても良く理解できますし、"**もう少し綺麗に**"という表現をより技術的なものにできたら(発端となった質問から持ってくると"依存を増やさない範囲でよりシンプルに"とか"型やデータは増えても構わないのでできるだけグローバル変数を使わないように"とかでしょうか？)オントピックになりそうです。

個人的な感想ですが、発端となった質問は作業の粒度が大きすぎたので"**もう少し綺麗に**"としか表現できなくなったのではないでしょうか。
一息に綺麗なコードを求めずに、もう少し気に入らない部分/改善したいことを細分化するとより回答しやすい質問になりそうだと思いました。

---

コメントを受けて追記します。

発端となった質問がなぜ問題視されたのかは究極的には以下に収束するように思います。

> ### 避けた方がよい質問はありますか？
>
> 主観的であったり、炎上を招く内容であったり、**長々とした議論が必要になるような質問は避けてください**。ここは明快な答えが出せるような質問のための場所です！

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)から引用(強調はわたしによるものです)

わたしも発端となった質問は強く問題になるほど主観的な質問だとは思いませんが、個人の主観によって回答が変わってしまうのは確かなので残念ながら議論の余地がありました。
例えば、"美しいコード"や"素晴らしいコード"がとても主観的なものだというのは同意いただけると思います。
それに対して"綺麗なコード"はもう少し具体性があって、一定のプログラム経験がある人ならふんわりとしたイメージを共有できそうだとわたしは思います。
しかしながら、この"ふんわりとしたイメージ"が"美しいコード"と同程度に主観的なものだと感じる人も居るだろうとも思います。
相容れない異なる2つの意見があるので長々とした議論になってしまいます。

また、stackoverflow.comはあとから質問を見た人がQ&Aを見て参考にしてもらえる質問や回答を集めるサイトです。
この観点からだと、[c++](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)の初学者が最も綺麗なコンストラクタの書き方が知りたいと検索して発端となった質問にたどり着いた場合、"この書き方が綺麗だ"が複数あるとどれを選ぶべきか迷ってしまいそうです。
質問内の表現により具体性を求めるコメントや回答は、あとから質問を閲覧するすべての人が混乱しないように/選択に迷わないようにしたいのだと思います。

---

追記中に更にコメントがあったので。

わたしはstackoverflow METAに存在する [std::mapの初期化を綺麗にしたい(続き)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3802/25936) に対して回答を投稿しています。
ですので

> 綺麗なコードというのが主観的だと思うのは勝手ですが、この質問は十分に技術的であり、それ以外に正しい表現方法がありません。
> 議論するつもりもないのですが、正解が1つしかない回答を求めてるわけではなく、続きの質問自体が残らないことに対処の不適切さを感じるので、保全した次第です。

に対するわたしの考えを回答としています。

Comment: すみませんが、回答ではありませんね。あと大きかったわけではありませんよ。個々に気にする部分が違う「綺麗」を俯瞰したいという意図がなかったわけではないし、諸々の事態に備えた「ベストプラクティス」(この表現は正解が1つしかないイメージで良くない)を導出したい意図があったかもしれませんが、私の意図を介在させず、自由に「綺麗」だけで書かれたノウハウと技術の詰まった回答群を見たかっただけですよ。まあstd::mapの静的インスタンスの初期化が大きいとかはそもそもないと思いますけど。

Comment: [「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: 質問が「メタ」と無関係なのは知ってます。私がここに移動させたのではないので、文句は別の人に言ってくださいね。

Comment: 何度も言ってますが、回答ではありませんよ。保全理由に回答は必要ないのです。また議論が必要だと思っているのは、私以外の人間で、誰となんの議論をするつもりなのかまるで分かりません。それこそ別途質問をあげて勝手にやって頂ければいいかと思います。

Comment: @dameo 議論を望まれないのであれば、この質問が再びja.stackoverflow.comへ移管されるのをお待ちください。再び移管された場合はこの回答は不適切なものになるので可能であればわたしが、そうでなければ権限がある方に削除していただくことになります。

Comment: この議論に意味はないので、最初の質問から何度もそう書いてますよ。私が言ってるのは質問の回答になっていないということだけです。